# Unity project Parser error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am am having trouble with a piece of code from a tutorial i found online. i keep getting a parser error by the line `public static Vector2`.

Here is the the code below. I can't find anything wrong with it and would love suggestions on why this error keeps coming up. Thanks!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Grid : MonoBehaviour {
    // The Grid itself
    public static int w = 10;
    public static int h = 20;
    public static Transform[,] grid = new Transform[w, h];
}
public static Vector2 roundVec2(Vector2 v) {
    return new Vector2(Mathf.Round(v.x),
                       Mathf.Round(v.y));
}
public static void deleteRow(int y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
        Destroy(grid[x, y].gameObject);
        grid[x, y] = null;
    }
}
public static void decreaseRow(int y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
        if (grid[x, y] != null) {
            // Move one towards bottom
            grid[x, y-1] = grid[x, y];
            grid[x, y] = null;

            // Update Block position
            grid[x, y-1].position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
        }
    }
}
public static void decreaseRow(int y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
        if (grid[x, y] != null) {
            // Move one towards bottom
            grid[x, y-1] = grid[x, y];
            grid[x, y] = null;

            // Update Block position
            grid[x, y-1].position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
        }
    }
}
public static void decreaseRow(int y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
        if (grid[x, y] != null) {
            // Move one towards bottom
            grid[x, y-1] = grid[x, y];
            grid[x, y] = null;

            // Update Block position
            grid[x, y-1].position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
        }
    }
}
public static bool isRowFull(int y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x)
        if (grid[x, y] == null)
            return false;
    return true;
}
public static void deleteFullRows() {
    for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
        if (isRowFull(y)) {
            deleteRow(y);
            decreaseRowsAbove(y+1);
            --y;
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> Parser Error: Unexpected symbol 'Vector2', expection 'class', 'delegate', 'enum', 'interface', partial', or 'struct'

Comment: it comes up with a parser error.

Comment: Go on...
Post that parser error in it's entirety please.

Comment: Also the [unity] tag is for the Unity Application Block, a dependency injection container.  It clearly says not to use it for Unity Game Engine questions.  [unity3d] is the correct tag

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected symbol 'Vector2', expection 'class', 'delegate', 'enum', 'interface', partial', or 'struct'

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are closing the class after line:

```
public static Transform[,] grid = new Transform[w, h];
}
```

Move the brace to the end of the file.

Also, any reason why everything is defined as `static`?  A `MonoBehavior` is intended to be an instance object attached to a game object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You are closing the class to early and

```
public static bool isRowFull(int y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x)
        if (grid[x, y] == null)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

is missing brackets on the for loop.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Grid : MonoBehaviour {
    // The Grid itself
    public static int w = 10;
    public static int h = 20;
    public static Transform[,] grid = new Transform[w, h];

    public static Vector2 roundVec2(Vector2 v) {
        return new Vector2(Mathf.Round(v.x),
                           Mathf.Round(v.y));
    }
    public static void deleteRow(int y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
            Destroy(grid[x, y].gameObject);
            grid[x, y] = null;
        }
    }
    public static void decreaseRow(int y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
            if (grid[x, y] != null) {
                // Move one towards bottom
                grid[x, y-1] = grid[x, y];
                grid[x, y] = null;

                // Update Block position
                grid[x, y-1].position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void decreaseRow(int y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
            if (grid[x, y] != null) {
                // Move one towards bottom
                grid[x, y-1] = grid[x, y];
                grid[x, y] = null;

                // Update Block position
                grid[x, y-1].position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void decreaseRow(int y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
            if (grid[x, y] != null) {
                // Move one towards bottom
                grid[x, y-1] = grid[x, y];
                grid[x, y] = null;

                // Update Block position
                grid[x, y-1].position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    public static bool isRowFull(int y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
            if (grid[x, y] == null)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static void deleteFullRows() {
        for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
            if (isRowFull(y)) {
                deleteRow(y);
                decreaseRowsAbove(y+1);
                --y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```